# How to measure time elapsed, immune to system time server automatic updates

Tags: java, time, java.util.date, elapsedtime

My servers and desktops are configured to automatically adjust their time via network ntp time servers.

This means that if I use the easy method `beginDate.getTime()-new Date().getTime()`, there is a chance I'm not getting an accurate number of elapsed milliseconds.

How can I write code that is immune to system clock updates and leap second adjustments?